# oracle sql : selecting fields from two views with no field overlap

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Working in Oracle SQL Developer (3.2.20.09).

I have to create a view from two source views.  For example, Fields 1-3 exist in View A and  Fields 4-6 exist in View B.  There is zero overlap.  I cannot select both views and pull all their fields into a subsequent view because combined they have too many fields (the two source views have combined well over the total fields allowed in a single view).

Is it possible  to tell my pl/sql package procedure: get this field from view A.  If it's not there, go to view B?

Or is a better solution to use all_tab_columns or some other meta(?) solution, look to see who owns Field 1 and grab it from there?

I don't have any experience with either of the above two options so would appreciate a lot of guidance.

Or is there simply a better third option?

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the number of columns in view A and B? I can't think of why one would have *that* many columns. Hundreds, ok, but thousands?

Comment: Definitely not possible.  That is definitely NOT my call.

Comment: Sorry, just asking. I don't have a solution then. But just out of professional interest, how can you have so many columns, what kind of data is stored in those views?

Comment: No offense taken!  Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a *view* with more than 1000 columns. If the combined number of columns of your view A and B is less, you can simply create a third view using SQL in a worksheet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_3 (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6) 
AS
SELECT a1,   a2,   a3,   NULL, NULL, NULL FROM view_a UNION ALL
SELECT null, null, null, b4,   b5,   b6   FROM view_b;
```

Comment: My initial question was not well written.  I should have said "For example, fields 1-3.  In reality each of the two source views hold much more than 3 fields and when combined, exceed the Oracle limit.

Comment: Huh? An Oracle table can have 1000 columns, not sure about views. Are your views close to that?

Comment: Just tried, a view can have 1000 columns, too. After that, there is an error "ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000"

Comment: I have over 1400 total columns.

Comment: Ouch! What about the datatypes of the columns of view A and B?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  But there are multiple types: numeric, string, etc in each of the two source views.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If all columns had been of the same datatype, one could have tried `UNPIVOT` or something.